# How to click on an Item of a LazyColumn that is scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here is my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
@Preview
fun ClickScrollingList() {
    val state = rememberLazyListState()
    val isDrag by state.interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()
    LaunchedEffect(isDrag.not(),state.isScrollInProgress.not()) {
        while (isDrag.not() && state.isScrollInProgress.not()) {
            state.animateScrollBy(
                value = 100f,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    1000,
                    easing = LinearEasing
                )
            )
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        state = state,
    ) {
        items(10000) {
            Text(
                "I am $it",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {
                        // TODO: Not Work
                    }
            )
        }
    }

}
```

When the list is scrolling, I can't click Item. I know this is because LazyColumn consumes the click event, which causes the item's clickable to fail to respond to the click event.

I want the item to be clicked while the list is scrolling, which means that if the finger touches the screen and then slides for a certain distance and then lifts up, I don't want to trigger the click event of the item, because this is the scrolling list instead of clicking on the item .

How do you achieve the above requirements？

Comment: You really don't want that. It'd be very annoying for the user. Especially since it'll be different from all other scrollables in all other apps.

Comment: Brother, I understand, but when you work for a certain company and the product manager needs you to implement this function, it is not very important whether you want it or no.

Comment: I feel your pain, brother. I'm afraid I can't help you, though. You may have to dive deep into `LazyColumn` internals to figure this one out.

Comment: I have used pointerInput() api to solve this problem